# QT how to update gui element from main context without a thread

Tags: qt, user-interface, qthread

I have a question regarding the update of gui elements like a progress bar.

If I make a loop from 1 to 100 in the main context and send an update signal in this loop, the percentage bar will be set to 100% directly after the loop is finished - the single steps are not displayed

If I outsource the loop to a thread and send the signal from there to a slot of the main context then the percentage bar is updated step by step.

As I have read this is because the main thread waits until a running process / loop is finished before a gui update is executed (very simply expressed).

Is there a way to do this looped update in main context without a thread?

Answer (score -1):

You can run loop in main thread and use `QApplication.processEvents()` inside this loop to process signals, progressbar will update incrementaly, but between this calls UI will be unresponsive.

It's cheap and dirty solution you can use to temporary solve problem if you don't have enough resources to properly solve it with worker or thread.

Comment: I had also seen this before but isn't it not advised because it contradicts the concept of QT to intervene hard in the event control?